# Get the data type from a field in MSproject

Tags: c#, ms-project

I'm trying to get the data type of a selected field in MSProject. There are 8 types of data(Cost, date, text,....) and I'd like to develop a small add-in with Visual studio which makes some calculation depending on the type of data I have selected.
With the help of this site, I found how to get the name of the field:

```
Application.ActiveSelection.FieldNameList[0]
```

(It could be helpful for the next step, If I select more than one field ==> Do nothing)

but I'm not able to find a way to return the data type of the selected field
Someone has an idea how I could do that?
[For example, if I select this field, my program has to return: text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GjVH.png)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to build a map of FieldName or FieldID to data type.

Keep in mind that date fields can also contain text (e.g. ActualStart will contain NA until there is a date in that field).

Also, use the task's native property to get the data rather than the `ActiveCell` property or the `GetField` method which return the displayed value.

For example, if the active cell is a duration field showing 2 days:

- `ActiveCell` returns "2 days", "2d", or "2 d", etc. depending on the user's configuration.
- `ActiveCell.Task.GetField(pjTaskDuration)` returns the same thing.
- `ActiveCell.Task.Duration` returns 960 (Int32).

**Update**

For custom fields that the end user creates, `TryParse` can be used to determine the likely data type. Here's a simplistic vb example:

```
Dim s As String
Dim d as Date
With Application.ActiveSelection
    s = .Tasks(0).GetField(.FieldIDList(0))
End With
If Date.TryParse(s, d) Then
    ' it is a date
Else
    ' it's not a date, maybe check to see if it's an integer
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer
But The problem with this method is in case of Custom field
If I create a custom field once I have deployed my solution, I couldn't get the type (as this custom field wouldn't be in my map)

Comment: Use `TryParse` to determine the data type of a custom field. See updated answer for more details.